# How to merge two id's from same model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Model Market

```
class Market(models.Model):
    market = models.CharField(max_length=285, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    parent_market = models.ForeignKey(
        'ParentMarket', null=True, blank=True, related_name='parent_market', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None)
    
    def __str__(self):model
        return str(self.market)
```

I want to merge two id's of Market to another id EX: id2 and id3 to the id1 which fall under same Parent Market.

**Advertising Public Relations(Parent Market)**

id1(child1)=(id2(child2),id3(child3))

All data of child2 and child3 should merge with child1.

Comment: What do you mean by merge?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ex: Food, Fish are two different markets. I want to merge all data of Fish to Food. I mean both id's will become one id, Fish will become Food and without  loosing the data.

Comment: Do you mean you have Foreign Keys pointing to Fish and Food and want all of them to point to one Market? You can't `merge` per say, you just have to create a new instance of market and update other models Foreign Keys.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat please check i updated my question. Parent Market having ForeignKey relation with Market. I want to merge 3 different markets to one.

Comment: Your question is unclear, your Market models have only a CharField and two foreign keys, what do you want to merge? What does merge **mean**? If you want your models in one list / iterable the answer below should work for you.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Merge means all records of certain id should merge in to another id. I have thousands of emails for one market which should merge. There is nothing to deal with ForeignKey. I want to combine data of two id's to one.

Comment: Then you simply need to point the Foreign keys of all these emails to the Model instance you want. There is no such thing as **merge**. Please clarify your question properly by editing and also add your Email model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
data = Market.objects.filter(pk__in=[id_list])
```